# Difference between different hardware of computer of recent times

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, chipset

While searching for good desktop for software development I came across many configuration.I become confuse over different thing as I don't have detail knowledge of Hardware.

Difference between Core I5 4570 and Core I7 4770 ? I came to know that core i7 has hyper threading and what is use of that and how does it effect or benefit while working with virtual machine.

Difference between Intel H81 Chipset and Q87 Chipset ? what to choose and how ?

My main purpose for desktop is for software development which include .net development , 
Android development, planning to use different virtual machine in Host OS. I hardly play any high end games.

Which is good configuration for above purpose and mainly considering future into mind ? ( At least next 7-8 years . I can upgrade RAM but not other thing )

Let me know your advice about different hardware.

Comment: This would be better for [chat]

Comment: I have edited my question now.

Comment: Your question is still in essence a shopping recommendation ("What is a good configuration?"), and in other aspects much too broad. You're asking many things at once. Honestly, if you go to [chat], our *Root Access* room, there are hardware experts just waiting to help you. You'll get better advice, much more tailored to your needs. Then you don't even have to keep your question generic.

Answer (score 1):

If money **is not** an impediment, go for the best one, the `#3`. You'll have a powerful rig plus it'll work great for some years to come without any upgrade. Just give the proper maintenance and it'll be good. Maintenance is **obligatory** on all computers, don't forget that.

But, if you want to save some cash, your best bet would be the `#1`. However, either chipset has its own different applications, but simply put:

- `H81`: Home simple use. Only some SATA ports and reduced features. This is the *budget* choice.
- `Q87`: Office work. Some extra features that you would probably never use.

Here's a [good comparison between them](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Z87-H87-H81-Q87-Q85-B85-What-is-the-difference-473/#ConsumerChipsets(Z87,H87,H81)). And since the processor and RAM specs are literally the same, there would be no apparent difference on performance between these two.

Comment: What type of maintenance required ? I think this applicable to all computer.

Comment: Like cleaning it regularly, changing the thermal compound, removing old or unuseful apps and files, checking smart data and defragging your disks (if applicable). Every six months is the longest recommended time between physical maintenance and 2 months for software maintenance.

Comment: @arielnmz but please never ever defrag a SSD. Please don't even think of it, you would kill it pretty fast..